# Why does my class not show in vue but my conditional class does?

Tags: vue.js

I want to show two classes in my `button`. One that is conditional on a `Boolean` data value like `"hideLeftArrow"` and another class that shows up as the default like `arrowBtn`. The conditional class shows but the default class doesn't. What is wrong with my syntax in the following:

```
:class="[{ hideArrow: hideLeftArrow }, arrowBtn]"
```

My full code for reference

```
<template>
  <div class="showcase-container">
    <button
      @click="showRightArrow"
      :class="[{ hideArrow: hideLeftArrow }, arrowBtn]"
    >
      <img alt="left arrow" src="../assets/leftArrow.svg" class="arrow" />
    </button>
    <a
      v-for="game in games"
      :key="game.id"
      :class="{ hideGame: game.hide }"
      :href="game.link"
      target="_blank"
      >{{ game.name }}</a
    >
    <button
      @click="showLeftArrow"
      :class="[{ hideArrow: hideRightArrow }, arrowBtn]"
    >
      <img alt="right arrow" src="../assets/rightArrow.svg" class="arrow" />
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      games: [
        {
          name: "Tryangle",
          link: "https://google.com",
          id: 1,
          hide: false,
        },
        {
          name: "BagRPG",
          link: "https://youtube.com",
          id: 2,
          hide: true,
        },
      ],
      hideLeftArrow: true,
      hideRightArrow: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showLeftArrow() {
      this.hideLeftArrow = !this.hideLeftArrow;
      this.hideRightArrow = !this.hideRightArrow;
      this.games[0].hide = true;
      this.games[1].hide = false;
    },
    showRightArrow() {
      this.hideLeftArrow = !this.hideLeftArrow;
      this.hideRightArrow = !this.hideRightArrow;
      this.games[0].hide = false;
      this.games[1].hide = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "../styles.scss";
.showcase-container {
  .hideArrow {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .arrowBtn {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
  }
  .hideGame {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're aiming for this, with quotes around `arrowBtn`:

```
:class="[{ hideArrow: hideLeftArrow }, 'arrowBtn']"
```

Otherwise `arrowBtn` will be treated as a property name and not a string..
That said, I'd probably do it this way instead:

```
class="arrowBtn"
:class="{ hideArrow: hideLeftArrow }"
```

`class` allows you to have both a static and a bound version on the same element.